# Define relationships with ckanext-hierarchy plugin

Tags: ckan

I would like to use the ckanext-hierarchy plugin. I've read the "instructions" on this site https://github.com/datagovuk/ckanext-hierarchy
but I really understand nothing at all.

How can I create some parents/children relationships between files?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you want to do is not what the `ckanext-hierarchy` plugin does.

The plugin allows you to define a parent-child relationship between **organizations**: for each organization, you can either set a parent organization (thus making it a a sub-organization), or leave it empty so that it is a top-level organization.

This allows you to model a complex organization made of different departments / offices.

The plugin is not meant to define relationships between **datasets** or **resources**.